# wp add inline style in loop

Tags: php, wp-enqueue-style, css

I want to add inline styles thanks to the wp_add_inline_style wordpress function.

The inline styles will be added in a loop.
In my case, I output an isotope grid in my loop and this grid can have differents css customization for each grid.

Actually I have this php script:

```
function grid_register_styles(){
    $themeversion =  wp_get_theme()->display('Version');
    wp_register_style( 'grid-style', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url'), array(),     floatval($themeversion) , false  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'grid_register_styles' );

function grid_inline_styles($guttercss) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'grid-style' );
    wp_add_inline_style( 'grid-style', $guttercss);
}

/* this is the function used for the loop */
function grid_init() {

    /* There is some stuff before */

    /* I calculate a variable in order to apply a style base on some options */
    $guttercss  = '.gutter-'. $gutter .' .to-item-wrapper {';
    $guttercss .= 'margin: '. $gutter/2 .'px !important;}';

    /* Then I call my function to output inline css style */
    grid_inline_styles($guttercss);

    /* There is some stuff after */

}
```

This code works in the loop and output different css style for each generated isotope grid.

However, the generated css is in the footer instead of the head....

I success to put it in the head with an add_action() but it can't only works outside the loop and only one time.

I think that I don't correctly understand the way to use wp_add_inline_style().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `grid_init()` runs inside the Loop, then it executes *after* the page `head` and after the associated hooks-- `wp_head`, `wp_enqueue_scripts`, etc. PHP executes line by line in sequence, so if you miss a hook you just missed it. You can't go backwards. The script/style enqueueing subsystem does have to ability to put things int he footer though, and in this case that is the only option. I am sure that is what you are seeing.

The markup you are getting *might* work, but it is also invalid. Styles have to be in the `head`.

The simplest solution, and probably the best, is to `echo` inline `style=` tags in your markup.

If that solution doesn't work then you will need to:

1. Loop through the Loop in the head of the document-- probably in the
   `wp_enqueue_styles` hook
2. generate the markup
3. reset the Loop
4. then let the page load

There is obviously additional processing time involved in that, but unless you have a lot of posts per page, you probably won't notice.

Comment: thank you for your anwser. Yes my added inline styles are placed inside the footer. In fact at the begining, I was created a `<style></style>` at the begining of the html grid. But it's not w3c valid. So I decided to create inline style thanks to worpdress function. I think I can't use `wp_add_inline_style()` because I also load a lot's of stuff in ajax. My only solution is inline style and it will works of course. Does `<div style="<?php echo $gutter; ?>` is consider as a dynamic inline style?

Comment: Yes, it is constructed dynamically, so it is a dynamic style.

Comment: Ok thank you! I asked this question to be sure, because I'm french and sometimes I'm not sure about some definitions...